# How to use bitmasks to allow/disallow manipulation of certain bits

Tags: bit, bitmask

I have a 32 bit value which represents 32 individual states. 
I also have another 32 bit value which controls which bits are either locked or can be altered by an application.

For instance ( using a 4 bit mask for succinctness )

```
Example 1
Value          1010
Lock Mask      1000 - i.e. the 4th bit is locked, i.e. can't be altered
Incoming value 0100
New Result     1100 - 4th bit unchanged

Example 2
Value          0011
Lock Mask      1000 - i.e. the 4th bit is locked, i.e. can't be altered
Incoming value 1100
New Result     0100 - 4th bit unchanged
```

Can someone kindly explain how I could achieve this. Maybe I need to change the mask so that it show bits that can be changed, i.e. 0111 in the above example... I don't know.

Regards
Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a C-like language where `&` is bitwise-and; `|` is bitwise-or; and `~` is bitwise-complement:

```
new_value = (value & locked) | (incoming & ~locked);
```

You could use `+` instead of `|`, if you felt it was more readable.